# no uevents triggered when disc inserted to USB dvd drive

Tags: linux, usb, udev, scsi

Any reason why no uevents are triggered whenever I insert a disc to my USB dvd rom drive?  I do get uevents whenever I connect and disconnect the drive to the computer.  Currently running a custom linux 3.0.35 kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I had to do two things to get uevents to trigger for my USB dvd drive.

1. Set `/sys/block/sr?/events_poll_msecs` to some number greater than 0, in my case, I set it to 2000.
2. Open the device as soon as I get a uevent.

Setting `events_poll_msecs` causes the kernel to poll the device and report a uevent when it detects a change.  However, no other uevents will be triggered until something in user space `fopen` the device.

Comment: Works on Raspian / Raspberry Pi / USB-CDROM. was set to `-1` and never triggered when a CD was inserted. Thank you!